# php prevent database connection in each request

Tags: php

I have a method in connection class which returns a dbconnection instance so I can make query with that.

```
class Connection
{
    public $dbh; // handle of the db connexion
    private static $instance;
    public $resultBool;
    public $connectedDbName;
    public $resultString;
    public $directed;
    public static $deviceid;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=webfilter;port=3306;connect_timeout=15', 'root', 'company');
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->directed = false;
        $this->resultBool = true;
    }

    public static function getConnection()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }

       ...
       return self::$instance;
}
```

At first request, there is a connection required so I step into this connection function that's ok. but why I need to make connection again even there is so obvious I will use same connection.. it seems cause performance issue..

here is my function which makes real job. I use dbObject to make queries on db, but for each time I need to connection instance(getconnection) to do it.

```
    $dbObject = Connection::getConnection();
    $request = $dbObject->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $request->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

is it possible to save existing connection for next request of same users or another way to pass connection operation

Comment: do you know the singleton pattern?

Comment: @sebastianbrosch no.. can you talk about it a little(whats it for)

Comment: a singelton is a pattern to create only one object of a class. i can provide a solution for you - give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already use the singleton pattern. This is only working for multiple connections in one request. For every request this class creates a new object of the connection class. A PDO instance can't be serialized or unserialized or saved on a session. I think there is no way at the moment to do this.